# Ubuntu available for smart phones?

Tags: 11.04, tablet, ubuntu-touch, smartphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

Recently, we have heard a lot about different powerful tablets and smartphones with operating systems such as Android or iOS. Now fortunately we see Ubuntu 11.04 will be available for tablets too. My question is that whether this version of Ubuntu will be available for smart phones with phoning features too? I mean can we have it on smart phones such as Samsung Galaxy Tab1?

Thanks in advance. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Kubuntu Mobile technology preview was part of the [10.10 release](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/10.10-release). I don't believe it is being shipped on any real hardware yet, but you can [download it](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu-mobile/releases/10.10/release/) to try out in a virtual machine. Builds for Natty are also [available](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/kubuntu-mobile/daily-live/current/).

[image: pics!]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, Ubuntu was not designed for phones. There are some [hacks](http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2010/03/10/video-htc-touch-pro2-runs-ubuntu/) to make it work on phones, but not in a usable way.

PS. Looks like there was a project called [Ubuntu Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Mobile), but it's already dead.

**Edit:** [Ubuntu for phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone) has been announced, but it still isn't shipping yet.