# How do I install Ubuntu for Phones?

Tags: phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

I know they [just announced it](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/), but I'm wondering if there's any way to peak at the upcoming goodies right now.

13.04 alpha?

PPA?

Source code?

Comment: This should help   -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it

Comment: I searched and didn't find that question earlier. Sorry.