# here can I download Ubuntu Mobile?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

I keep reading stories in the Press about Ubuntu Mobile, but where is the download? I can't develop for an OS I can't get hold of!