# Create Application for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: application-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

I am android developer and want to start [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) Phone development. I want to develop in JAVA. Please help me out to get started!

Comment: Useful link: http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/

Comment: I don't think this is dupe of that one (which I asked). OP wants info on **how to start developing** for [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android) or [Ubuntu for phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone), not sure which.

Comment: Voted for reopen, Because it is not exact duplicate

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Ubuntu Mobile OS is being developed, [Here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) is page Describes information that Every Ubuntu Mobile OS application developer needed. Go there and get started to build your Mobile application.