# How Can I install Ubuntu on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: galaxy-nexus

How Can I install ubuntu system in my android phone Galaxy Nexus ?

Comment: Be aware that Ubuntu on Nexus 7 is not yet stable. It is under heavy development and therefore is likely to have a lot of bugs and errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is 'Ubuntu for phones' and how can I get it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu desktop, Ubuntu for Android, or Ubuntu for phones?

Comment: **Clarification:** This question is about **Samsung *Galaxy Nexus* (i9250)**, and NOT **ASUS / Google *Nexus 7***.  *My answer, same as: @hhlp.*

Comment: Can anyone tell us when will we have a stable build for maguro ?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu for Phone, has not been released to install in Samsung Galaxy Nexus phones yet.  It has been rumored that it will be released towards the end of Feb 2013 as a developer platform.  This means that it will not be 100% fully functional for general public yet.

Ubuntu for the Nexus 7 TABLET is available now.  This is the Ubuntu Desktop version not for Gnex Phone.

Answer (score 0):

This link describes all, go through it https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

Comment: work for galaxy nexus ????

Comment: @user118399: As we all now aware of the news for Official release of Ubuntu on phones and tabs in coming future. But there are users who have installed Ubuntu successfully, one of the user commented like this _"I am now using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung Slate 7 tablet. This is quite expensive, but it's because it's a notebook. i5 quad core, 4GB ram etc. The result is super-nice. Luckily, I had chances to install Linux on quite many tablets since 2003. Until now, Slate7 + Ubuntu 12.04 is the best."_ so its totally your call.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @user68186 True I will try to edit the answer so that it explain briefly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Note, your comment related to Samsung Slate 7 tablet does not apply to Galaxy Nexus, as the former is **Intel i5 chip based tablet** and the later is an **ARM Cortex-A9 chip based phone.**

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is no way to install Ubuntu for Phones - the one that was announced yesterday. Regular Ubuntu can be installed officially only on ASUS Nexus 7, not on Samsung Galaxy Nexus. There is a way to install Ubuntu with "chroot", which makes Ubuntu run "inside" Android. That's relatively slow. Very slow. And many apps won't run, as the system won't have enough memory. How to install Ubuntu 12.04 this way:

[[Guide] How to install Ubuntu on Android.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1730546)

Comment: i dont want to make my Gnex look like a desktop :(

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: do you know when will be Available for galaxy nexus ??

Comment: 8/01/12. You can sign up here: https://forms.canonical.com/manhattan/

Comment: Thats ok. Anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is tested on galaxy nexus and procedure to install is described here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install?action=show&redirect=TouchInstallProcess

I am also a Galaxy Nexus owner and going to try the same in couple of days.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.