# Download Ubuntu for Nokia E7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nokia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

Where I can download Ubuntu for phones and how to install it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please consider the search function on this site first before asking questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu phone will never run on a Nokia E7 because it does not meet the [necessary requirements](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/operators-and-oems).

Furthermore it is not yet available. This product is announced but still in development.