# Ubuntu for Phones - Downloadable ROM?

Tags: android, downloads, ubuntu-touch, phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)

Will Ubuntu release the OS to download?

I have the Galaxy Nexus. I read on different pages that Ubuntu will not be downloadable, just preinstalled on phones. But some sites mean that Ubuntu for the galaxy nexus will be aviable to download in february.

Who knows the truth? I really would love Ubuntu on my gnex.

Thank You.

Comment: The fact that Ubuntu for phones uses Android drivers means that it'll be available for free download.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu for Phones ROM will be available in late February 2013.

> The image will be made available for download in late February, and while the only phone we've seen running the OS is a Galaxy Nexus, Shuttleworth made it clear last week that *it should be relatively easy to load up the OS on any Android device.*

Reference: http://www.phonearena.com/news/Ubuntu-for-phones-image-will-be-available-in-late-February_id38400