# installation of Ubuntu 12 in to a existing smart phone

Tags: smartphone, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is ‘Ubuntu for phones’ and how can I get it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it)
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

I would like to install Ubuntu 12 on my phone. It is a Windows 6.5 smartphone from Samsung.

How can I do that?