# 'Ubuntu for Tablets' -- when available?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

When will the tablet version of Ubuntu (not desktop) be able to be installed on a Nexus 7. I do not think it can now (since I do not even think they have finished it) but if so, post a tutorial.

Comment: You can install the developer preview, but be warned it's not meant for daily use. http://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-can-i-get-it

Comment: I can't exactly give you a tutorial but google search  "Ubuntu touch" and you can find all the necessary information. But as stated above it is not meant for daily use nor is it finished.

Answer (score 0):

The final version will not be available till 2014

Comment: Can you include a citation for this?

Comment: I just read about it in the internet and i don't remember the source

Comment: If you can find the source (you found it before, so you may be able to find it again...) that would make this answer considerably more robust and authoritative, plus people would have a source to go to if they want more information.

Comment: I just searched and didn't find it, but i`m sure the mentioned time was 2014