# Ubuntu Phone OS developer preview

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Can this new Ubuntu phone OS developer preview be installed on my HTC desire (bravo) ?
or is it strictly for Nexus devices?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/235317/44179

Answer (score 0):

The offical releases are for the Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10.
However there are a lot of people working on ports for other devices.
The place to go and check for your device would probably be the xda-developers ubuntu touch ports forum: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2098

You can also get in touch with a lot of helpful people via irc (freenode #ubuntu-phone).

**WARNING:** Remember this is a developer preview it is not ready to be used on your daily driver.