# Ubuntu Edge; Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-edge

I have been looking forward to Ubuntu Touch for quite a bit of time, due to it's desktop like functionality and beautiful display. But now I have heard of the Ubuntu Edge, and I am confused on the difference between the two.

What I am getting at is: will there be a true Ubuntu phone (the Ubuntu Edge) in 2014 while in October or November of this year the Ubuntu Touch OS will be available to use and boot up on Nexus products, OR is the Ubuntu Touch just a first model of the Ubuntu phone while the Ubuntu Edge is a second generation, more advanced model?

I am mainly worried because the edge is sort of [lacking funding](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge) at this moment and I would really enjoy being able to have a Ubuntu phone product within the next year.

Comment: Ubuntu Edge is one thing, Ubuntu Touch is another thing. Ubuntu Touch will be available on Andoid devices whether or not the Edge campaign is successful. Read [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android).

Comment: @edwin This seems like an answer. If so, maybe post it (or something like it, with a bit of expansion) as one? This is similar to information in other answers but more clearly stated, I think.

Answer (score 2):

### ***hardware vs. software***

**Ubuntu Edge** is a bespoke, limited edition smartphone device (platform). It will run both *Ubuntu Touch* and *Android*.

See:

http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge <-- The offer, and video

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge <-- basic background

Or do a *Google* search ..

---

**Ubuntu Touch** is Ubuntu (Linux) with a touch-interface. Its current focus is on the 'phablet' form factor.

See:

[What is Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu for Phones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-touch-ubuntu-for-phones/235476#235476)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch is the software while Ubuntu Edge is the 'superphone'.

Ubuntu Touch can be downloaded and installed on a similar spec'd smartphone running Android. It is still in the development stage. If you have a Nexus smartphone, particularly the latest one, you can get the mobile OS and test it.

Ubuntu Edge on the other hand, as being campaigned by Canonical, will use Ubuntu Touch and Android as its operating systems so you have three operating systems in one device - Ubuntu for desktop, Ubuntu Touch and Android. Ubuntu Edge will be available mid next year.

The main features of Ubuntu Edge are shown and explained well in this [video by Canonical](http://youtu.be/EtNhlVn3ETQ).

Answer (score 0):

You are confused with Ubuntu Edge and Ubuntu Touch.

> is the Ubuntu Touch just a first model of the Ubuntu phone while the
>   Ubuntu Edge is a second generation, more advanced model?

Actually, Ubuntu Touch is an operating system for smartphones. Currently it is under development and is available for testing. On the other hand, Ubuntu Edge is a smartphone from Canonical with a very high specifications (superphone..?). So, Ubuntu Touch is an OS like Android; Ubuntu Touch is a device like Nexus.