# Is Ubuntu Touch support available for Android Lollipop or Android M?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is Ubuntu Touch support available for porting to latest devices that runs Android L or Android M?
To run Ubuntu touch on Android devices, some of the components from Android are required (E.g, Modified kernel to support Ubuntu Touch, Android HAL, drivers etc.) The initial Ubuntu Touch port for the list of compatible devices were based on Kitkat. 
Is there a working Ubuntu Touch port available for the latest Android devices that runs Android L or Android M?
What level of support available from Ubuntu Touch for porting the components (modified kernel, HAL, drivers based on Android L or M) to these devices?

Comment: Your question does not seem to be valid. Take a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-touch-ubuntu-for-phones

Comment: Updated the question with more info based on comments

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch is not an application running on Android, but another mobile operating system that replaces Android (it might run side by side, as you can install both Linux and Windows at the same time).

You cannot say "Android L or Android M is compatible", but have to look at the [limited list of compatible devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support).

Comment: Yes, I know Ubuntu touch is an OS and not an application on Android. Rephrasing my question may clarify.

Comment: To run Ubuntu touch on Android devices, some of the components from Android are required (E.g, Modified kernel to support Ubuntu Touch, Android HAL, drivers etc.) The initial Ubuntu Touch port for the list of compatible devices were based on Kitkat. The question was keeping this in mind. Is there a working Ubuntu Touch port available for the latest Android devices that runs Android L or Android M? What level of support available from Ubuntu Touch for porting to these devices?

Comment: A device running Android M or L is not generally compatible with Ubuntu Touch, each device needs some special adjustments. The Ubuntu Touch kernel is not an Android kernel, it just pulled in some parts from it.